# update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for mozilla-javaplugin.so

Tags: openjdk, update-alternatives

I'm trying to switch from Java Development Kit (JDK) 8 to JDK 11 in Bionic. Installation went fine:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk
$ sudo update-java-alternatives -l
java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64      1101       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0- openjdk-amd64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

So I thought I could switch by:

```
$ sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
```

However, that returns:

```
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for mozilla-javaplugin.so
update-java-alternatives: plugin alternative does not exist: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/IcedTeaPlugin.so
```

That file does indeed not exist, but neither does it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64. The same goes for mozilla-javaplugin.so. So why does update-alternatives complain about it not being available, and how can I make it stop caring?

Answer (score 2):

Just ignore the error(s).

`update-java-alternatives` has done all it needs to do.
That's most important and what it counts.