# Java 11 to 8: update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for mozilla-javaplugin.so

Tags: java, jdk, openjdk, update-alternatives

I have Java 11 and 8 in my Ubuntu 18.04, side by side.
I mean to set Java 8 as the default.

What I get:

```
    $ sudo update-java-alternatives --set /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
    update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for mozilla-javaplugin.so
```

```
    update-java-alternatives: plugin alternative does not exist: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/IcedTeaPlugin.so
```

How can I get both plugins if they exist, work.

I am not sure if using (see [this](https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/issues/3075))

```
    sudo update-java-alternative —jre-headless -s java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

is ok, so I did not try it.
**Could it break anything?**
The Following are results after `update-java-alternatives`

```
    $ sudo update-alternatives --config java
    There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).
```

```
  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1101      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1101      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode

$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.04.1-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

This is the opposite change from

[update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for mozilla-javaplugin.so](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078946/update-alternatives-error-no-alternatives-for-mozilla-javaplugin-so)

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2402155

Related:

https://serverfault.com/questions/814064/set-jdk-8-as-the-default-java-on-debian-8

Comment: So you have Java 8 as default now and solved your problem.

Comment: Although those read like error messages, they are more like warnings. You can ignore them because the update-java-alternatives command has properly reconfigured the alternatives to enable all of the java components (including java and javac if its a jdk) to the desired version. @Kulfy made this comment below but it wasn't very obvious

Comment: @Sancho, did you solve this issue? I have exatly the same problem on Ubuntu eoan.

Comment: @codyLine - I am not sure... this happened some time ago.

Answer (score 12):

You can select the default Java Version by running the following command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Select the Java Installation you want to use per default by typing the selection number. Check the default Java Version by running *`java -version`*. It should print something similar to the following:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.04.1-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: It seems `update-java-alternative` does the same as `update-alternatives --config java`, and more. So I wouldn't expect this to solve the issue.
Perhaps at best it doesn't attempt performing the actions which lead to the messages, but then it would possibly be not useful anyway.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: No.
Would you mind posting the exact procedure to follow?
How should I check if the ending result is ok (in addition to getting rid of the error message)? Please see updated OP; the actions implied by your command seem already executed by what I did.

Comment: @sancho.s If you want to check that if alternatives are changed, run `java -version`

Comment: @Kulfy - Already did that, I will add it.

Comment: I updated my answer. You can check the Java Version by running `java -version`.

Comment: @sancho.s You can ignore those errors. IcedTea and Mozilla Java are just extra plugins. Java consists of many plugins. When you updated alternatives, it tried to update alternatives for that too but can't find those. They aren't required as well. So you can ignore those errors and consider them just as warnings. Your default java version is now JDK8.

Answer (score 0):

`jre-headless` is okay if the java app you want to run has no gui.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

has potential inconsistent java env issue. See [Setting JDK 7 as default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272187/setting-jdk-7-as-default/272190)